# After sending email a security warning comes in email body

Tags: php, email, pdf

I am using php mail function with PDF attachment. Here everything is working fine but in the email body this following warning comes

"This email has an attachment that allows unverified scripts to run on your computer when opened. Be careful"

can you suggest ? what is the problem

Comment: It is most likely being added by your mail server or email program. Have you tried sending to a different address?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the correct headers for sending attachments?

You can try using this pattern (tested and working):

```html
$subject = 'SUBJECT';
$message .= 'Hello world'."\n";

$content = file_get_contents($file);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

$separator = md5(time());
$eol = "\r\n";

$headers = "From: ME <me@mymail.org>".$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;

$body = "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol;
$body .= $message.$eol;

$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol;
$body .= $content.$eol;
$body .= "--".$separator."--";
```

$filename is your attachment, $file is the full path (including $filename).